# Why timestamp subraсtion gives the minus in result?

Tags: abap

My App start time is 20191015110000.

1. The last best time for client_1 was: 20191015113000.
2. The last best time for client_1 was: 20191015103000.

Now I want to get this result after my App will finish the process.

1. Last Client Best-Time was: 20191015113000 New Client Best-Time is: 2019-10-15T11:30:00+03:00
2. Last Client Best-Time was: 20191015103000 New Client Best-Time is: '' (i.e blank)

But I can't get the necessary result. Can anybody indicate my mistake?

Here's my ABAP code:

```
DATA: lv_best_time           TYPE timestamp VALUE `20191015090000`,
      lv_campaign_start_time TYPE timestamp VALUE `20191015110000`,
      lv_new_best_time       TYPE string.


CONSTANTS: lc_one_hour TYPE i VALUE 3600.

IF lv_best_time IS NOT INITIAL.

  DATA(lv_ts_subtract) = cl_abap_tstmp=>subtract( EXPORTING tstmp1 = lv_campaign_start_time
                                                            tstmp2 = lv_best_time ).

  IF abs( lv_ts_subtract ) < lc_one_hour.
    lv_new_best_time = ``.
  ELSE.
    lv_new_best_time = |{ lv_best_time TIMESTAMP = ISO TIMEZONE = `MY TIMEZONE` }| && `+03:00`.
  ENDIF.
ENDIF.

WRITE: |Last Cleient Best-Time was: | && lv_best_time && ` ` && |New Client Best-Time is: | && lv_new_best_time.
```

Comment: You said what you want to obtain, please explain what you currently get so that to make it clear for everybody.

Comment: Sorry but there is absolutely no negative result in your example.

Comment: It seems your `lv_campaign_start_time` var is empty, thus condition with abs is not satisfied and `lv_new_best_time` var is not calculated too.

Answer (score 0):

Following result is already available with your code.

```
Last Client Best-Time was: 20191015113000 New Client Best-Time is: 2019-10-15T11:30:00+03:00
```

Second Result

```
Last Client Best-Time was: 20191015103000 New Client Best-Time is: '' (i.e blank)
```

You ahve to change lc_one_hour from 3600 to 7201 or greator.

`CONSTANTS: lc_one_hour TYPE i VALUE 7201`.